# How to poll simple website for updates?

Tags: html, polling

I have a professor who randomly updates his website with homework due tomorrow and seems to expect us to check it every hour.

This sounds like a job for a program.

His website is simple and entirely html, not even any javascript.  How could I programatically detect any changes/updates to his website?

Answer (score 5):

Check the `Last-Modified` Response header.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to do this...extra credit would then be to run it through a diff engine and email yourself the results.  That would even prevent you from having to figure out what changed...

Comment: He always just adds to the end, so figuring out changes isn't tough.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch and md5 the content of each page. Then store and compare with previous values. Note that this is sensitive down to the character level.

Alternativelly, setup a [Google Alert](http://www.google.com/alerts) for `site:your-professors-website.com` and have the updates delivered to your email or via rss.

Answer (score 1):

setup a cron job to periodically wget or curl the URL, then grep for relevant text, then send yourself an email if interesting results are found...